# Wso2 identity server; how use Active Directory for identity provider?

Tags: active-directory, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I know Identity Provider is for authenticating users for service provider. I want to use Active Directory for authenticating users.

For this - can I use an identity provider?

Comment: This would be helpful for you https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ycIplHrB6a4

Answer (score 0):

You want to get the users in Active directory to login to your service providers through Identity Server, you can configure your Active Directory as a user store in the Identity Server. Follow the instructions mentioned in the official documentation [here](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/setup/configuring-a-read-write-active-directory-user-store/).